# WPF: How do I use one User control for multiple different Click events

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, controls

I'm trying to create a User control for all the buttons on my homepage, every user control should have a different Click event. I'm trying to solve this by adding a property to the User control (which works for the label and image) but i can't find any solution for the Click event.

ImageLabelButton.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SC.UI.WPF.Controls.ImageLabelButton"
<Grid>
    <Button Name="BtnClick">
        <StackPanel>
                <Image Name="ImageButton"/>
                <Label Name="LabelButton"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

ImageLabelButton.xaml.cs:

```
....
  <!-- works -->
  public string Name
  {
      get { return this.LabelButton.Content.ToString(); }
      set { this.LabelButton.Content = value; }
  }
  <!-- works -->
  public ImageSource SetSource
  {
      get { return ImageButton.Source; }
      set { ImageButton.Source = value; }
  }
  <!-- doesn't work -->
  public EventHandler ButtonAction
  {
      get { return BtnClick.Click; }
      set { BtnClick.Click= value; }
  }
```

Implementation.xaml:

```
....
<controls:ImageLabelButton Name="first" SetSource="test.png" ButtonAction="Click1"/>
<controls:ImageLabelButton Name="first" SetSource="test.png" ButtonAction="Click2"/>
<controls:ImageLabelButton Name="first" SetSource="test.png" ButtonAction="Click3"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set the event handler up as a property of the user control and set it in the usage code:

User control XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Button Name="BtnClick" Click="BtnClick_DoClick">
        <StackPanel>
            <Image Name="ImageButton"/>
            <Label Name="LabelButton"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

User control codebehind:

```
    public EventHandler<RoutedEventArgs> ButtonAction;

    private void BtnClick_DoClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ButtonAction != null) ButtonAction(sender, e);
    }
```

Implementation XAML:

```
<controls:ImageLabelButton Name="first1" SetSource="test.png" />
<controls:ImageLabelButton Name="first2" SetSource="test.png" />
<controls:ImageLabelButton Name="first3" SetSource="test.png" />
```

Implementation code behind:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        first1.ButtonAction = Button1;
        first2.ButtonAction = Button2;
        first3.ButtonAction = Button3;
    }

    private void Button3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { MessageBox.Show("Pressed 3"); }
    private void Button2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { MessageBox.Show("Pressed 2"); }
    private void Button1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { MessageBox.Show("Pressed 1"); }
```

Although you can't set the event handling in XAML this way.

Answer (score 0):

You need a RoutedEvent on your user control that can be accessed from Implementation.xaml

ImageLabelButton.xaml

```
<Button Name="BtnClick" Click="Submit_Click">
    <StackPanel>
            <Image Name="ImageButton"/>
            <Label Name="LabelButton"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

ImageLabelButton.cs

```
private void Submit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(ClickEvent, this));
    }

    public static readonly RoutedEvent ClickEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
        "Click", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(MyUserControl));

    public event RoutedEventHandler Click
    {
        add { AddHandler(ClickEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(ClickEvent, value); }
    }
```

Implementation.xaml

```
<controls:ImageLabelButton Name="first" SetSource="test.png" Click="Click1"/>
```

Implementation.xaml.cs

```
private void Click1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```